# How to install SpringSource Tool Suite (STS) on Windows?

Tags: android, spring

When I try opening STS.exe it gives me the follow error:

> An error has occured. See the log file
>   C:\Users......... etc
>
> ---
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).

Here is the full log file:
http://pastebin.ca/3177801

I have messed around with environment variables.

Under user variables it lists two TEMP variables.

Under system variables Path reads:

```
C:\Windows\system32;
C:\Windows;
C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common
```

I'm running Windows 7 with Java 1.6.0.29 installed.

---

EDIT: I uninstalled Java 1.6 and reinstalled with latest version 1.8. Now STS gives me error with exit code 13. View image here: http://oi62.tinypic.com/2m6of3d.jpg

In my case Java 1.8 is 32, which will have to be replaced with the 64 bit version. The environment variables will also have to be updated to point to Java 1.8 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of OP)*.

I deleted the old 1.6 environment variable and made sure the new 1.8 variable was pointing to the right location.